# All users post are not lising for the admin in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Recently I have created a website with drupal7. I am facing some problem like administrator are unable to view all post created by users. its only showing the admin own post(admin/content) and each user there own post. But I would like to view all post list to the admin and there own posts for each users. I know its default things in the D6. How it possible for D7?

Comment: Is everything set well on permissions page? /admin/people/permissions

Comment: Yes, I have given all permission check to the administrator. Is there any other area do I need to check?

Comment: What I would try is turning all the modules and switching to some standard theme to make sure that it's not some bug in 3rd party code...

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I am using default 'Seven' theme for the administration view, anyway I got a temporary solution like, I have created a block in the dashboard with recent post, there I can edit and delete all post. But I know this is not a real fix for it.